# Add a scroll to next section link on header button, positioned fixed at the bottom with in the div

Tags: html, css

I have a header section with background video, as video height is bigger than the screen height, I am trying to add a small arrow icon at the bottom of the header section (of screen section because bottom of header is quite below).

So, I want to add arrow section to the bottom of the screen fixed, and while keeping fixed this arrow should be keep showing on other div, means it need to be shown only on this `kssite-home-intro-se`

Here is my code:

```
<section class="kssite-home-intro-sec">
    <div id="kssite-intro-sec-overlay"></div>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe
                src="<?php echo CFS()->get('video_url',5); ?>?background=1"
                frameborder="0"
                allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture"
                allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-to-next-sec">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-5x fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
</section>
```

and CSS:

```
.kssite-home-intro-sec {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    background-position: center center;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.arrow-to-next-sec{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:49%;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 99;
}
.arrow-to-next-sec a{
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Here, this is working fine,but this arrow remains there on the bottom of the screen even if we scrolled past this `kssite-home-intro-sec` section.

I have also, tried with `absolute` instead, but it positioned itself to the bottom of the div, and bottom of the div is not with in the screen and we have to scroll little bit to view this scroll button.

How, could I make it as I wanted.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/npk5dw0m/

Comment: Your snippet is not working here! Please use code with visible UI. OR you can use `position: absolute` instead of `fixed`.

Comment: i have added js fiddle link, maybe you missed it, but I have already mentioned that absolute too not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position:sticky` if you want to achieve this.

```css
.arrow-to-next-sec {position: sticky; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: 2;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-5A8nwdMOWrSz20fDsjczgUidUBR8liPYU+WymTZP1lmY9G6Oc7HlZv156XqnsgNUzTyMefFTcsFH/tnJE/+xBg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section class="kssite-home-intro-sec">
    <div id="kssite-intro-sec-overlay"></div>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe
                src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/347119375?background=1"
                frameborder="0"
                allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture"
                allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-to-next-sec">
        <a href="#second-div"><i class="fa fa-5x fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="second-div">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates placeat esse voluptas, rem eveniet eos laboriosam architecto. Amet, repellendus minus dicta hic tenetur quaerat, blanditiis laborum obcaecati suscipit odio iusto.
  </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates placeat esse voluptas, rem eveniet eos laboriosam architecto. Amet, repellendus minus dicta hic tenetur quaerat, blanditiis laborum obcaecati suscipit odio iusto.
  </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates placeat esse voluptas, rem eveniet eos laboriosam architecto. Amet, repellendus minus dicta hic tenetur quaerat, blanditiis laborum obcaecati suscipit odio iusto.
  </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates placeat esse voluptas, rem eveniet eos laboriosam architecto. Amet, repellendus minus dicta hic tenetur quaerat, blanditiis laborum obcaecati suscipit odio iusto.
  </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates placeat esse voluptas, rem eveniet eos laboriosam architecto. Amet, repellendus minus dicta hic tenetur quaerat, blanditiis laborum obcaecati suscipit odio iusto.
  </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates placeat esse voluptas, rem eveniet eos laboriosam architecto. Amet, repellendus minus dicta hic tenetur quaerat, blanditiis laborum obcaecati suscipit odio iusto.
  </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates placeat esse voluptas, rem eveniet eos laboriosam architecto. Amet, repellendus minus dicta hic tenetur quaerat, blanditiis laborum obcaecati suscipit odio iusto.
  </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates placeat esse voluptas, rem eveniet eos laboriosam architecto. Amet, repellendus minus dicta hic tenetur quaerat, blanditiis laborum obcaecati suscipit odio iusto.
  </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates placeat esse voluptas, rem eveniet eos laboriosam architecto. Amet, repellendus minus dicta hic tenetur quaerat, blanditiis laborum obcaecati suscipit odio iusto.
  </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates placeat esse voluptas, rem eveniet eos laboriosam architecto. Amet, repellendus minus dicta hic tenetur quaerat, blanditiis laborum obcaecati suscipit odio iusto.
  </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates placeat esse voluptas, rem eveniet eos laboriosam architecto. Amet, repellendus minus dicta hic tenetur quaerat, blanditiis laborum obcaecati suscipit odio iusto.
  </p>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In case if this snippet is not working in stackoverflow here's a codepen [link](https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/VwWgmVG)

No matter how much height is the video it will stick to the bottom

Comment: Doesn't seems to work, the arrow seems to be gone outside of video, also, the arrow icon is on left no of center.

Comment: I have updated the codepen link kindly check now.